# How to check how many players have unlocked an Achievement in Play Game Services?

Tags: android, google-play-games, google-play-console, achievements

I need to know exactly how many players have unlocked a particular achievement in the lifetime of the game. Is that possible?

In the documentation they say this:

> On your Achievements page, you can find statistics that include:
>
> - Percentage of players who unlocked an achievement
> - Number of players who unlocked an achievement
> - Average time to unlock an achievement

*https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3423625

So I understand from that lines that you can check general data but not particular data of each achievement separately. Can someone confirm that?

The number of players of my game is still very low and statistics are not visible... for my previous game it was necessary to wait months until statistics activated. I need to know it now, because if it's impossible to check this separately I will be forced to integrate Firebase Analytics just for this thing, and I prefer to keep the game with the least amount of SDKs possible.